# how do i get python working on nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, python

I've just installed python 2.7.1, it works fine from the command line.

I have php running fine on my nginx webserver.
it uses php-fpm.

how do i get python working on nginx?

thanks

Comment: You'd better specify what python software are you planning to run, most python web stuff has specific instructions about running it with certain webservers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct module for running python on nginx (there's a wsgi module but it's VERY buggy).

Your best option is to either use mongrel or passenger to run your python code over and use nginx as a proxy server in front of your application.

Comment: Or use gunicorn behind nginx as proxy.